# Difference between 3 apps setConcurrency(1) vs 1 app setConcurrency(3)

Tags: java, kubernetes, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have a question regarding Kafka concurrency with Spring Kafka. I have one Kafka topic `theimportanttopic` where many messages are being sent over it. Hard fact, this Kafka topic has three partitions. (Calling them theimportanttopic-0 theimportanttopic-1 theimportanttopic-2)

It is known Kafka does not allow multiple consumers from one same group to consume messages from one same partition. I.e, no two consumers within one same group can consume from theimportanttopic-0.

My Spring Kafka application code is as follow:

```java
@Configuration
class KafkaConsumerConfig {

    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "mykafka.com:9092");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        return props;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs());
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String>> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        factory.setConcurrency(1); //HERE
        return factory;
    }
}
```

```java
@Component
class KafkaListenersExample {

    Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(KafkaListenersExample.class);

    @KafkaListener(topics = "theimportanttopic", groupId = "uniquegroup")
    void listener(String data) {
        LOG.info(data);
        doSomethingImportantWithTheData(data);
    }
}
```

With that, I am having a hard time understanding the difference between the two constructs:

Suppose this application is already dockerized and a cloud environment is ready for use.

Design number 1: this application, since it is in a container deployed on the cloud, like Kubernetes, spin up three instances of it.
By definition, I will have three of those "apps" and each one of the app will consume from one out of the three partition.

```
kubectl get pods
my-app-AaAaAaAaAa-AaAaA
my-app-BbBbBbBbBb-BbBbB
my-app-CcCcCcCcCc-CcCcC
```

(and hypothetically, my-app-AaAaAaAaAa-AaAaA consumes theimportanttopic-0, my-app-BbBbBbBbBb-BbBbB theimportanttopic-1, my-app-CcCcCcCcCc-CcCcCtheimportanttopic-2)

Design number 2:
On the other hand, I can have one, and only one of this app my-app in container, set the concurrency to 3. (same code as above, just one line change)

```java
@Bean
public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String>> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory =
            new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
    factory.setConcurrency(3);
    return factory;
}
```

What are the differences between the two designs please?

Which one is preferred and why please?

This is not an opinion based question. What is the performance, the cost, the pros and cons between design number 1 and design number 2?

Comment: Try it out and measure. There is no easy answer as it all depends on the available resources, how well your code is written. So the only thing to do is measure it.

Comment: You probably don't need to multiply memory. 3 cores should be able to distribute threads in parallel. As mentioned, measure your app heap space for memory, though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is high availability.

If you have any one pod, consuming all three partitions, and it stops, then you need additional config in k8s to have a RestartPolicy.

Alternatively, have a ReplicaSet with a maxContainers of 3, and then Kafka Consumer API can rebalance when any one of them starts/stops.

You can also look into KEDA to autoscale based on consumer lag.

Comment: Very clear answer. Upvoted. Before I accept, suppose high availability is a constant. (Suppose the containers never crashes for either of the two solutions, I just want to take this variable out of the picture, but based on what you say, I will go with design 1). Does it means, in terms of performance, 1 java kafka consumer running in its own container, multiply by 3, has no difference than one bigger container, but only one, with .setConcurrency(3)?

Comment: As mentioned, you need to do your own benchmarks to adequately capture performance differences. There will be a difference, yes, but it may be unnoticeable

Comment: Also, kubernetes can (and will) restart the pods at any time, especially during cluster upgrades, for example. So, don't assume pods are constant

Comment: Agreed. starting my benmark right away, but it seems from a design point of view, those are equivalent (in terms of performance only)

Comment: So far, not seeing any difference between the two (while the services are up) it seems like this ```.setConcurrency(3)``` was created for usecases unrelated to Kubernetes

Comment: Or, can still be used in Kubernetes. If you have 9 partitions, you could run 3 pods with 3 concurrency... Eventually, you will run into a thread-per-core limit on your containers, in which case, you can add more pods